# additional code in my dev console when running local environment angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, bower

I'm running angularJS with gulp and bower...when i run gulp serve to run my local environment and go into the dev tools to debug, i get this additional code in the debug console on my pages, not sure how to get the debug console to just show me my components. Has anyone run into this issue before?

```
var cov_1238jb1h2 = function () {
      var path = '**',
          hash = '**',
          global = new Function('return this')(),
          gcv = '__coverage__',
          coverageData = {
        path: '**',
        statementMap: {
          '0': {
            start: {
              line: 1,
              column: 0
            },
            end: {
              line: 13,
              column: 5
            }
          },
          '1': {
            start: {
              line: 5,
              column: 31
            },
            end: {
              line: 7,
              column: 5
            }
          },
          '2': {
            start: {
              line: 9,
              column: 4
            },
            end: {
              line: 11,
              column: 65
            }
          }
        },
        fnMap: {
          '0': {
            name: '(anonymous_0)',
            decl: {
              start: {
                line: 1,
                column: 1
              },
              end: {
                line: 1,
                column: 2
              }
            },
            loc: {
              start: {
                line: 1,
                column: 13
              },
              end: {
                line: 13,
                column: 1
              }
            },
            line: 1
          }
        },
        branchMap: {},
        s: {
          '0': 0,
          '1': 0,
          '2': 0
        },
        f: {
          '0': 0
        },
        b: {},
        _coverageSchema: '1231i3io1h31i41h21b1v1515v12ou51u25o15g1o1l51'
      },
          coverage = global[gcv] || (global[gcv] = {});

      if (coverage[path] && coverage[path].hash === hash) {
        return coverage[path];
      }

      coverageData.hash = hash;
      return coverage[path] = coverageData;
    }();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came across the same problem. You're probably using Babel to translate from ES6 to ES5. Babel uses plugin called [babel-plugin-istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul) which appends this additional data to your code. If you don't care about karma and tests (like me) or simply coverage, you can disable this plugin in two easy steps:

1. Remove `"istanbul"` from plugins in `.babelrc` file.
2. Uninstall plugin by invoking this command: `npm uninstall babel-plugin-istanbul --save-dev`.